# How to write a while loop where I'm using -d option in test condition?

Tags: bash

How do I test a directory in a while loop where if the directory doesn't exist, then it does the following blank things. I'm trying to prompt the user for input when the directory doesn't exist so the user can retry. Once they get it right, then the script exits.

My script has an infinite loop and I don't know how to fix it. Here is what my bash script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

source_dir=$1
dest_dir=$2

while [[ ! -d "$source_dir" ]]
do
        echo "This is not a directory. Enter the source directory: "
        read "$source_dir"
done

while [[ ! -d "$dest_dir" ]]
do
        echo "This is not a directory. enter the destination directory: "
        read "$dest_dir"
done
```

Comment: What are _blank things_?

Comment: @user1934428 I was talking about executing the commands between the do and done statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly,

```
read "$source_dir"
```

does not make sense. To understand this, assume that your script is called with the parameter FOO. Hence, you first set `source_dir` to *FOO*, and the test `[[ -d $source_dir ]]` will do a `[[ -d FOO ]]` and the directory FOO does not exist. Therefore you perform your `read` command, which will parameter-expand into `read FOO`. This means to read one line from STDIN and store it into the variable FOO.

If you want to change the value of the variable `source_dir`, you have to do a

```
read source_dir
```